How to efficiently manage data binding and event handling in ASP.NET MVC views?
I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC project and have run into some challenges regarding the use of view classes. Specifically, I want to ensure that my views are clean, maintainable, and efficiently handle data binding and events.
Code:
@model MyProject.Models.MyViewModel

<form asp-action="UpdateData" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    <div>
        <label asp-for="Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

How can I better handle events in my views without cluttering them with too much logic?

Better - how? What aspect / part needs to be better - and what does that mean, exactly?

Its hard to say what would be the best and efficient way for you because, your scenario or requirement is not clear. What challenges are you getting now?
